# how to fix breadcrumb from bad result and url

Tags: php

I have attached a breadcrumb and is now running. but how to tidy up the results in order to function.

this code

```
<?php


$crumbs = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

foreach($crumbs as $crumb){
    ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb) . ' ');
}

$urls = "http://example.com";

foreach($crumbs as $crumb){

$urls .= "/".$crumb;

echo '<li><a href="'.$urls.'">';
echo $crumb;
echo '</a></li>';

}
?>
```

and the result is

```
Home / / pages / contact
```

How to remove one slash after home?

and result for the url

```
http://example.com//pages/contact
```

i've tried to fix but still not solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add each 'breadcrumb' to an array in your loop, and then implode the array after the loop, adding the slashes.

```
$urls = "http://example.com";

$breadcrumbs = array();

foreach($crumbs as $crumb){    

    $breadcrumbs[] = "<li><a href='$urls/$crumb'>$crumb</a></li>";

}

echo '/'.implode('/',$breadcrumbs);
```

Comment: You need that closing `)` on implode mate.... Also, it's `href='$url/$crumb'`...not just `href='$url'`.

Comment: Is it like this?<?php


$crumbs = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

foreach($crumbs as $crumb){
    ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb) . ' ');
}

$urls = "http://example.com"

$breadcrumbs = array();

foreach($crumbs as $crumb){
 
$breadcrumbs[] = "<li><a href='$urls/$crumb'>$crumb</a></li>";

}
echo '/'.implode('/',$breadcrumbs);
?>